# Use object's func when declaring it

Tags: javascript

I want do declare a variable inside an object using a function that is being declared in that same object. But when I try I get an error:

```js
const obj = {
  alpha: 4,
  
  somestuff: function()
  {
    return 120;
  },
  
  // Does not work
  beta: this.somestuff()
  // Does not work
};

// Works
obj.beta = obj.somestuff();
console.log(obj.beta);
// Works
```

How can I make it work **when** object is being declared, not after it was declared

Comment: That's not a *perfect* fit, but it should contain how to do it (ignoring the first answer since I don't think getters are appropriate here).

Comment: Well, it looks now that it's better to simply do this after the **obj** is declared, but still thanks))